# Azure Function (python) insert to Azure SQL keep getting an error

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, azure-functions

I am new to Azure Functions and am hitting an error I can't seem to get past.  The Azure function (Python) is supposed to pull data from an API call and insert the results into an Azure SQL db.  I am doing local debugging and keep getting this error.  I have verified that all the column names and data types are matching.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for any assistance!!!!

```
import logging
import requests
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func
from datetime import date
# from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

server = 'xxx' 
database = 'xxx' 
username = 'xxx' 
password = 'xxx' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

def get_properties():
    params = {
            'IntegrationPartnerID': 'xxxx',
            'ApiKey': 'xxx',
            'AccountID': 'xxx',
        }
    url = 'https://api.myresman.com/Account/GetProperties'

    data=requests.post(url, params)
    response=data.json()

    df=pd.json_normalize(response, record_path='Properties')
    
    df = df.rename(columns={'PropertyID':'propertyid', 'Name':'property_name', 'StreetAddress':'street_address', \
    'City':'city', 'State':'state_code', 'Zip':'zip_code', 'Phone':'phone', 'Email':'email', \
        'Manager':'manager','CurrentPeriod.Start': 'currentperiod_start', \
            'CurrentPeriod.End': 'currentperiod_end'})
    
    df['propertyid']=df['propertyid'].astype(str)
    df['property_name']=df['property_name'].astype(str)
    df['street_address']=df['street_address'].astype(str)
    df['city']=df['city'].astype(str)
    df['state_code']=df['state_code'].astype(str)
    df['zip_code']=df['zip_code'].astype(str)
    df['phone']=df['phone'].astype(str)
    df['email']=df['email'].astype(str)
    df['manager']=df['manager'].astype(str)
    df['currentperiod_start']=pd.to_datetime(df['currentperiod_start'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    df['currentperiod_end']=pd.to_datetime(df['currentperiod_end'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    df['as_of_date']=date.today()
    return df


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    gp_data=get_properties()
    for index, row in gp_data.iterrows():
                cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO dbo.get_properties ('propertyid', 'property_name', 'street_address', 
            'city', 'state_code', 'zip_code', 'phone', 'email', 'manager', 'currentperiod_start', 
                'currentperiod_end') values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""", \
                row.propertyid, row.property_name, row.street_address, row.city, row.state_code, row.zip_code, \
                    row.phone, row.email, row.manager, \
                     row.currentperiod_start, row.currentperiod_end,row.as_of_date)
    cnxn.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

And here's the error:

[2021-03-22T21:05:02.971Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.get-properties-api-call. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'propertyid'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'property_name'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'street_address'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'city'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'state_code'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'zip_code'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'phone'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'email'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'manager'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'currentperiod_start'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'currentperiod_end'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 355, in _handle__invocation_request
call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
File "C:\Users\marks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 542, in _*run_sync_func
return func(**params)
File "C:\Users\marks\upwork_files\Taylor\get_properties\get-properties-api-call_*init**.py", line 54, in main
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO dbo.get_properties ('propertyid', 'property_name', 'street_address',

Comment: In SQL Server `'propertyid'` is a string literal. You probably want to use `propertyid` in the column list of your INSERT statement.

Comment: IOW - just list the names of your table in the insert list without string delimiters. E.g., `INSERT INTO dbo.get_properties (propertyid, property_name, ...`

Comment: That did it !!!!  THANK YOU SOOOOOO MUCH!

Comment: @bossjimmark  Is the error solved now? I just help them post it as answer, you can think about accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Very thanks for  AlwaysLearning and SMor's help.

- In SQL Server '`propertyid`' is a string literal. You probably want to
  use `propertyid` in the column list of your INSERT statement.
- IOW - just list the names of your table in the insert list without
  string delimiters. E.g., INSERT INTO dbo.get_properties (propertyid,
  property_name, ...

This can be beneficial to other community members.